# parallelizing lapply with parLapply does not recognize objects even though I suppied them

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply

I am trying to parallelize something with parLapply. I am exporting all necessary information to the cores, but somehow I am getting an error saying that it cannot find the object 'market_time' (first line of the function that is called in parLapply. However, this object is just a column of the data table 'dt' that I export to the cores.

```
library('data.table')
library('numDeriv')
library('snow')

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1], type = 'PSOCK')

 markets <- unique(dt[, market_time])
 R = 10000
 nu_p <- rnorm(n = R, -2, 0.5)
 nu_xr <- rnorm(n = R, 2, 0.5)
 nu_xm <- rnorm(n = R, 2, 0.5)
 nu_xj <- rnorm(n = R, 2, 0.5)

 clusterExport(cl,c('dt','nu_p','nu_xr','nu_xm','nu_xj')

 temp <- parLapply(cl, markets,calc_mc_w, dt=dt,nu_p=nu_p,nu_xr= nu_xr,
                 nu_xm=nu_xm,nu_xj=nu_xj)
```

where the function calc_mc_w calls:

```
calc_mc_w <- function(m, dt,nu_p,nu_xr,nu_xm,nu_xj){
  dt_mkt = dt[market_time==m,]
  market_time <- dt_mkt[, market_time]
  x_m <- dt_mkt[, x_m]
  x_j <- dt_mkt[, x_j]
  x_r <- dt_mkt[, x_r]
  p <- as.matrix(dt_mkt[, p])
  xi <- dt_mkt[, xi]
  p <- as.matrix(dt_mkt[, p])
  jacobian <- jacobian(function(x){calc_shares(x, x_m, x_j, x_r, xi, nu_p, 
                                               nu_xm, nu_xj, nu_xr, 
                                               market_time)},p)
  output <- dt_mkt[,c('prod','market','time','retailer')]
  
  #Get a system of equations with as many equations as unknowns
  retailers = unique(dt_mkt[, retailer])
  
  temp <- lapply(retailers,calc_mc_w_r,dt_mkt = dt_mkt, jacobian = jacobian)
  
  temp <- rbindlist(temp)
  output <- merge(output,temp,by.x = c('prod','retailer'),
                  by.y = c('prod','retailer'), allow.cartesian=TRUE)
  output
}

calc_mc_w_r <- function(r, dt_mkt, jacobian){
  dt_r = dt_mkt[retailer == r,]
  result <- dt_r[,c('prod','retailer')]
  rows = (dt_mkt[,'retailer']== r)
  jacobian_r = jacobian[rows,rows]
  result <- result[,mc_w := solve(jacobian_r, dt_r[,shares]+ jacobian_r %*% dt_r[,p])]
  result
}
```

The error I get is:
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'market_time' not found

If instead, I do not export the data table dt, but instead each column of it, I get the same error but just for 'jacobian' which is something that I calculate in the function (I do not want to calculate it across the whole dataset as it is super costly, which is why I just want to calculate it on each subset).

Comment: From a quick look: `clusterEvalQ(cl, loadNamespace("data.table"))`, or possibly `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))`, will probably do it.

Comment: PS. Use `library('parallel')` instead of `library('snow')` - the latter is a legacy package

Comment: When I try to execute your reprex,  I run into difficulty.  What is `market_time`?  where is it defined?  __Make sure your program runs on one node before you worry about multiple.__ I eagerly await your clarification.  The definition to `markets` depends on it, but it is not in the environment at the time the assignment is executed.

Comment: Additionally, `dt` is not defined.  What I think happened here may be that you wrote your reprex in an environment where `dt` and `market_time` had been defined sometime earlier, and you forgot to put them in your actual reprex script. Happens to the best of us.

Comment: Thank you all for the information! I managed to fix it.